# Can sphinx-apidoc include explicit docs for superclass methods?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-sphinx

I'm considering Sphinx for documenting Python projects.  I'd like the api docs for a class to contain docs for all of the methods that can be called from the class.  The default behavior seems to be to provide a links to superclasses.  Thus to see all callable methods I have to click back through the inheritance tree.  Docs I've seen produced by (I think) javadoc or doxygen show at least the names of all methods that can be called.

Is it possible in sphinx to display docs for local methods, and at least the names of methods defined in superclasses?   To me this is desirable.  Is there some reason that what I want is not such a good idea?  Is there some alternative approach from within Sphinx?

Plan B will be to explore Pydoctor.  Any suggestions for a Plan C, D, ... ?

Comment: Have you looked into the [`sphinx-apidoc` options](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html)? In particular, see `:inherited-members:`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I did see :inherited-members:, and I implemented it.  It did not produce the desired effect, although I expected it to.   I'm not sure it provided *any* effect.   But if you are telling me that it should have worked, then I'll look more closely at my sphinx files (conf.py, etc) to make sure they are structured correctly.  This is new for me, so I'm not at all sure everything is correct.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed, the inherited-members option provides the link to the superclass docs that I mention in the OP.  It does not provide mention of the superclass methods that are available to be called from the subclass.